# Probability that a cycle of a permutation ends at $k$th step

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Given a permutation of $1,\ldots,n$ we can decompose it into cycles (e.g., the permutation $(3,2,1,4) $ has cycles $1\to 3\to 1, 2\to 2, 4\to 4 $). Let's use the convention that the first cycle starts with $1$.

Let $X_k=1$ if a cycle ends at the $k$th step and $0$ otherwise (so that in the above example, $X_1=0,X_2=X_3=X_4=1).$
I want to show $$P(X_k=1)=\frac{1}{n-k+1}$$

I am having difficulty since I don't know how many different ways one of the cycles can end at the $k$th step. If $k=2,$ we have either a cycle (a) $1\to a\to 1$ or (b) two cycles $1\to 1,a\to a$. So the probability that $P(X_2=1)$ should be the sum that we are in one of these disjoint cases. The probability of (a) is $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n}$ since there are $n-1$ choices for $a$ and $(n-2)!$ ways to permute the remaining $n-2$ elements other than $1,a$; and the probability of (b) is $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n}$ since there are $(n-1)(n-2)!$ permutations fixing $1,a\not=1$.

This cannot be correct since the sum is $2/n$ while the formula says it's $\frac{1}{n-2+1}=\frac{1}{n-1}$. How can this be proved (for any $k$)?

Attached is the original source of the problem, #12 of Feller'Probability. 
[image]

Comment: In your example, I don't understand what you mean by $X_4 = 1$. $1\to 2 \to 3 \to 1 \to 2$, yes?

Comment: I don't understand your example.  In the permutation $\{3,2,1,4\}$ isn't $2$ fixed?

Comment: Nor do I understand the desired formula for $P(X_2=1)$.  As you say, there are two ways a cycle might end in $2$.  Either $2$ is fixed (probability $\frac 1n$) or $2\to 1$ (also probability $\frac 1n$).  So I see the answer as $\frac 2n$.  Am I misreading (or miscalculating)?

Comment: A useful page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics

Comment: @Chas Brown. By $X_4=1$ I mean that one of the cycles ends at the 4th step. Namely the last cycle which sends 4 to 4 is the 4th step in the cycle decomposition. I edited the question. By $1 \to 2 \to 1$, I mean that one is sent to the original position that 2 was in and that 2 is sent to the position that 1 was originally in (so 1 and 2 are swapped).

Comment: So if I understand correctly: we express a permutation $p$ of $[n]$ in standard cyclic form. This creates an ordering of the numbers in $[n]$ as they appear, left to right, in the cycles. $X_k = 1$ if the $k$-th element in that ordering is the last element of the cycle it belongs to; otherwise $X_k=0$. Thus for the permutation $(1,3)(2,5,4)$, $X_2 = X_5 = 1$, and all other $X_k=0$. In particular, $X_n=1$ in all cases.

Comment: @ChasBrown exactly.

Comment: For $X_2$, in your analysis of the (b) case, $a$ is constrained - it must be the smallest number that has not been used by a previous cycle; which means it must be $2$; i.e. we must have either $(1,a)$ or $(1)(2)$.

Comment: I find it quite unclear what the OP is asking. At the very least, they need to include a rigorous definition of "ends at the $k$th step".

Comment: You can find a proof with a nice explanation in Example 2.2.4. in Section 2.2 (page 51) of the 4th edition of *Probability: Theory and Examples* by Richard Durrett. This book is freely available on his website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of understanding this result.

Define a bijection $\Phi:\Omega_n\to\Omega_n$ on the set $\Omega_n$ of permutations. For a permutation $x= x_1 x_2\dots x_n$, move from right to left inserting a right bracket after every $x_k$ where $x_k=\inf\{x_k,x_{k+1},\dots, x_n\}$. Fill in left brackets where necessary. This is the cycle structure of a new permuation $\Phi(x).$

For example, if $x = 361975284$ then we get the cycle structure $(361)(9752)(84)$
 which gives $\Phi(x)=396821547$. *We adopt the convention that the smallest element in each cycle is written last, and that the cycles are ordered by smallest element.*

Since $\Phi$ is a bijection, if $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $\Omega_n$ then
so is $X=\Phi^{-1}(Y)$. The chance that a randomly selected permutation $Y$ will have 
a cycle completed at the $k$th step is the chance
that $X_k=\inf\{X_k,X_{k+1},\dots, X_n\}$, that is, ${1\over n-k+1}$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your example. Where are the brackets in your example? How did you decompose into those cycles?

Comment: Start at the end of $361975284$ and put a right bracket whenever the value is a "record low". We first meet the number $4$. Is this a record low? Yes, so we insert a right bracket, giving $361975284)$. We move one step to the left and meet $8$. Is this a record low? No, so no bracket. We move one step to the left and meet $2$. Is this a record low? Yes, so insert a right bracket, giving $3619752)84)$. We move one step to the left and meet $5$. Is this a record low? No, so no bracket. We move one step to the left and meet $7$. Is this a record low? No, so no bracket.

Comment: We move one step to the left and meet $9$. Is this a record low? No, so no bracket. We move one step to the left and meet $1$. Is this a record low? Yes, so insert a right bracket, giving $361)9752)84)$. Since $1$ is the smallest value over all we will not meet any more record lows: the final result is $361)9752)84).$ Fill in with *left* brackets where necessary to arrive at the result $(361)(9752)(84).$ This is a cycle decompostion.